# Regex to find length of the column value in sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I had created a query to find if the value I am passing is alphanumeric or number 
by using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  INTO l_col
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (l_columnvalue, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '');

IF l_col > 0 THEN
   NULL;
ELSE
   l_columnvalue := '"' || l_columnvalue || '"';
END IF;
```

This code checks if the `l_columnvalue` is number and if it is then `l_col` will become greater than 0 otherwise the `l_columnvalue` will be enclosed in quotes `" "` .

Now I want to check if the `columnvalue` is a number and its length equals to 7. If so, then it should not be in quotes `""`, otherwise if it is a number and its length less than or more than 7 then it should be in quotes.

How can I use regex for this ?

```
**Example :**
```

If the `l_columnvalue` is `15679` then

query1 will return 1 and the `if` statement will be executed accordingly.

if it is `'abdg12'` then query1 will return `null` then the else statement will be executed and the output will come as `"abdg12"`

Now I want if `l_columnvalue` is number and its length is not 7 e.g. : `123`
then query 1 should not return 1 instead the output should be `"123"`

How to go about it ?

Comment: Please edit your query with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done. Kindly check

Comment: Just append `and length(l_columnvalue) = 7` after where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning on implementing this logic in PL/SQL(looks like it), then a function(whether it's a standalone function or a part of a package function) could look something like this:

```
create or replace function nameTheFunction(
  p_expr in varchar2  -- based on information you've provided 
) return varchar2     -- an actual parameter may be either numeric    
is                    -- or alphanumeric, thus varchar2
  l_result  varchar2(101); -- adjust the size as needed
  l_isDigit boolean;
begin
  l_isDigit := regexp_like(p_expr, '^[[:digit:]]+$');
  return case
           when (l_isDigit and length(p_expr) < 7) or (not l_isDigit) 
           then dbms_assert.enquote_name(p_expr)
           else p_expr
         end;
end;
```

There is no need to use `select into` statement, no need to do an extra switch between PL/SQL and SQL engines. `regexp_like()` function can be directly used inside a PL/SQL block:

Test case:

```
column res format a11
clear screen;
with t1(col) as(
  select '1234567' from dual union all
  select 'ah123'   from dual union all
  select '1234'    from dual
)
select nameTheFunction(col) as res
  from t1
```

Result:

```
RES       
-----------
1234567     
"AH123"     
"1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another condition in your if like below

```
IF ( l_col > 0 AND length(l_columnvalue) > 7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use a regular expression to do this there are other options. For example, you can attempt to convert the string to NUMBER - if that succeeds, it's a number and you can check the length - if the conversion fails, it's not a number. For example:

```
DECLARE
  strNumeric_value    VARCHAR2(100) := '1234567890';
  strNonnumeric_value VARCHAR2(100) := '123A56789o';
  nValue              NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    nValue := TO_NUMBER(strNumeric_value);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      nValue := NULL;  -- not numeric
  END;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('strNumeric_value ' ||
                       CASE
                         WHEN nValue IS NOT NULL THEN
                           'IS NOT '
                         ELSE
                           'is '
                       END || 'numeric');

  BEGIN
    nValue := TO_NUMBER(strNonnumeric_value);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      nValue := NULL;  -- not numeric
  END;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('strNonnumeric_value ' ||
                       CASE
                         WHEN nValue IS NOT NULL THEN
                           'IS NOT '
                         ELSE
                           'is '
                       END || 'numeric');
END;
```

Share and enjoy.